# Action added in object studio is not getting reflected in process studio even after i refresh and save

Tags: blueprism

In object studio I added an object flow in "options tab" but this option does not reflect in process studio, under business object -> action section, even after I click refresh and save.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I moved a tag from the title to the tags section, so that your question can reach more people. I also made the image visible without having to go to an external website :)

Answer (score 3):

In Blue Prism v6, new Actions from Business Objects that existed at the time you opened the Process will be loaded every time you select the Reset button.

New Business Objects (those that did not exist when you first opened the Process) will not appear until you've closed and re-opened the Process.

Comment: Thank for your response esqew strangely i tried the same step you suggested multiple times earlier but without success. Not sure where is the problem. closed entire BP and tried that option to but still refresh or reset does not seem to help

Comment: @NirajK I assumed it went without saying, but ensure your new Action is published.